# Delete bulk rows in Big Query table based on list of unique ids

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

So I tried to delete some rows in Big Query table with simple query like this:

```py
client = bigquery.Client()
query = "DELETE FROM Sample_Dataset.Sample_Table WHERE Sample_Table_Id IN {}".format(primary_key_list)
query_job = client.query(query, location="us-west1")
```

Where primary_key_list is some python list contains a list of Sample_Table unique id like: `[123, 124, 125, ...]`

Things working good with small data I retrieve but when the primary_key_list grows, it gives me an error:

> The query is too large. The maximum standard SQL query length is
> 1024.00K characters, including comments and white space characters.

I realize the query will be long enough to reach max query length, and after searching on stack overflow I found out there's a solution to use parameterized queries, so I change my code to this:

```py
client = bigquery.Client()
query = "DELETE FROM Sample_Dataset.Sample_Table WHERE Sample_Table_Id IN UNNEST(@List_Sample_Table_Id)"
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
    query_parameters=[
        bigquery.ArrayQueryParameter("List_Sample_Table_Id", "INT64", primary_key_list),
    ]
)
query_job = client.query(query, job_config=job_config)
```

It stops giving me maximum standard SQL query length, but returns me another error exception, any idea to delete bulk rows from Big Query?

I don't know if this information is useful or not but, I'm running this python code on google cloud Dataproc, and this is just some function I recently added, before I add this function everything is working, and here's the log I've got from running delete using parameterized queries.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 320, in _send_until_done
    return self.connection.send(data)
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1737, in send
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1639, in _raise_ssl_error
    raise SysCallError(errno, errorcode.get(errno))
OpenSSL.SSL.SysCallError: (32, 'EPIPE')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1244, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1290, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1239, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1065, in _send_output
    self.send(chunk)
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 987, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 331, in sendall
    sent = self._send_until_done(data[total_sent:total_sent + SSL_WRITE_BLOCKSIZE])
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 326, in _send_until_done
    raise SocketError(str(e))
OSError: (32, 'EPIPE')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 368, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1244, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1290, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1239, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1065, in _send_output
    self.send(chunk)
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 987, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 331, in sendall
    sent = self._send_until_done(data[total_sent:total_sent + SSL_WRITE_BLOCKSIZE])
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 326, in _send_until_done
    raise SocketError(str(e))
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError("(32, 'EPIPE')"))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/a05a15822be04a9abdc1ba05e317bb2f/ItemHistory-get.py", line 92, in <module>
    delete_duplicate_pk()
  File "/tmp/a05a15822be04a9abdc1ba05e317bb2f/ItemHistory-get.py", line 84, in delete_duplicate_pk
    query_job = client.query(query, job_config=job_config, location="asia-southeast2")
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 2893, in query
    query_job._begin(retry=retry, timeout=timeout)
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job/query.py", line 1069, in _begin
    super(QueryJob, self)._begin(client=client, retry=retry, timeout=timeout)
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job/base.py", line 438, in _begin
    timeout=timeout,
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 643, in _call_api
    return call()
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 286, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 184, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 434, in api_request
    timeout=timeout,
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 292, in _make_request
    method, url, headers, data, target_object, timeout=timeout
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 330, in _do_request
    url=url, method=method, headers=headers, data=data, timeout=timeout
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 470, in request
    **kwargs
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError("(32, 'EPIPE')"))
```

Comment: According to this [post](https://groups.google.com/g/cloud-composer-discuss/c/Fd4aqZfgeeg) in google groups, you can try to upgrade the package  `requests` or/and the version of `OpenSSL`

Comment: @blackbishop already tried to upgrade requests and can confirm the previous error log is gone, but since I need to delete or update bulk rows (let's say 500.000+ rows) I found out using merge statement is more appropriate in my case (I need to delete or update data in the big query table with the data I just retrieve): https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement

Comment: Glad it helped to resolve the above error ;) Yes, merge is made for combining insert/update/delete operations.

Comment: @chairul may you post your solution as an answer, instead of comment?

Comment: @IgorDvorzhak thanks for the reminder, already posted as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@blackbishop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1386551/blackbishop) mention, you can try to upgrade requests to the latest version (in my case it solve the problem) but since I tried to update bulk rows (let's say 500.000+ row in Big Query, which every row have a unique id), turns out it gives me a timeout with small machine type Dataproc clusters that I used (if someone has a resource to try with better Dataproc cluster and success please feel free to edit this answer).

So I go with the Merge statement as documented here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement

The script would be like this to update existing rows (assuming I have the new data I retrieve and already load it to Staging_Sample_Dataset.Staging_Sample_Table):

```
def merge_data():
    client = bigquery.Client()
    query = """MERGE INTO Sample_Dataset.Sample_Table st
            USING Staging_Sample_Dataset.Staging_Sample_Table ss
            ON st.Sample_Table_Id = ss.Sample_Table_Id
            WHEN MATCHED UPDATE SET st.Your_Column = ss.Your_Column -- and the list goes on...
            WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ROW
            """
    query_job = client.query(query, location="asia-southeast2")
    results = query_job.result()
```

or I could delete bulk rows and call another function to load after this function executed:

```
def bulk_delete():
    client = bigquery.Client()
    query = """MERGE INTO Sample_Dataset.Sample_Table st
            USING Staging_Sample_Dataset.Staging_Sample_Table sst
            ON st.Sample_Table_Id = sst.Sample_Table_Id
            WHEN MATCHED THEN DELETE
            """
    query_job = client.query(query, location="asia-southeast2")
    results = query_job.result()
```

Answer (score 0):

the concept is looping the array of the ids you have and run the delete fro each one of them

it is just the structure, not the actual code. so it might need more than just tweaking

```
set arrlength = ARRAY_LENGTH(primary_key_list)
client = bigquery.Client()
WHILE i < arrlength DO
   query = "delete from Sample_Dataset.Sample_Table WHERE Sample_Table_Id=primary_key_list[OFFSET(i)]"
   query_job = client.query(query, location="us-west1")
   set i = i+1;

END WHILE;
```

Comment: But doesn't that count as 1 DML operation per loop? (correct me if I'm wrong), if yes then I will reach table operations limits in no time according to this: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#standard_tables (anybody can confirm this? because the last sentence said:  "the number of daily operations that are counted for the quota includes DML statements, but DML statements will not fail due to this limit.")

Comment: I was not aware of these limitations to be honest, and if every transaction counts against those limitations then you may have to contact them so you can clarify it and ask for a possible way to proceed with this